# Turn the background at different angles

Tags: jquery, image, html, css

Help please, I can not realize the background as follows:

*before*

[image]

*after*

[image]

**It is desirable to implement it for different screen sizes, and not just a picture.**

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If you want a background image that can be seamlessly tiled, you'll need a 45° rotation. Other than that, you'll just have to make it *really* big

Comment: @Pekka but you can code?

Comment: Change the first example to the second one using *code*? I don't think so, no. You'll need a graphics program to do that, the image to the bottom contains information that is not in the first one. (You can rotate an image however - for that, Google eg. `css rotate image`)

Answer (score 0):

you could make a big div with a css gradient background, i usualy use this site to make them: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ , and then rotate that div element using a css3 transform: http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate

Comment: Actually you can do the rotation with linear-gradient itself providing angle as a first parameter. Check mdn docs for linear-gradient https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient.